# Wget: Save URL when crawling webpages

Tags: wget

My problem with using wget is that some webpages end in `/`, but they are saved by wget as `/index.html`. Therefore, when I reconstruct the URL from the html file path, the corresponding page does not exist.

Is there a way I can save the original URL along with the HTML content of a page with wget? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this simple little script using wget and grep may be a great little helper:

wget --no-verbose --recursive --spider --force-html --level=DEPTH_LEVEL --no-directories --reject=jpg,jpeg,png,gif YOUR_DOMAIN 2>&1 | sort | uniq | grep -oe 'www[^ ]*'

Resulting in a list of all URIs depending on the DEPTH_LEVEL (e.g. 5) you set, it sorts out all pictures and forces to crawl html files. You can then save the output into a single file by adding > result.txt after the statement. You can simply modify the matching pattern, for example replacing the www into http:// in order to get more suitable results.

The script does not save any data or content from the web site. It just simply 'spiders' the structure and does not create any directories